# SQLSTATE 42601 DB2 INSERT INTO WITH chained SQL

Tags: sql, db2, sql-insert

I receive Error -104 and Sqlstate 42601 when trying to run my Code.
There is a simplified version beneath.

```
Insert Into <Table> (XXX, XXX) 
WITH <Name> AS (SELECT XXX))
SELECT XXX;
```

Comment: What is your database, DB2 is ? Tag it please. Please put the real code...Please format the whole code not only one part ?

Answer (score 0):

If I have table "test" like this:

```
create table test(a_col int, b_col int)
```

With no values. And I have table "test_2" like this:

```
create table test_2 (col1 int, col2 int)
```

with values:

```
insert into test_2 values(1, 2)
```

Then this code:

```
insert Into test(a_col ,b_col)
with TAB AS ( SELECT col1 as a, col2 as b FROM test_2) 
selecta, b from TAB;
```

will insert  values 1 and 2 into table "test" columns a_col  and b_col.

Here is a demo:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=6dbc4e056e4bb4f22680753a9b892f05)